# How can I use the RichText editor draftail in Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail, richtext, draftail

This is a very generic question so I don't have any code to show for it yet however I am wondering if anyone can give me a minimal example or guidance on how to use the draftail editor in Wagtail, but not in the admin, but on a public facing page.  I haven't managed to find any information on that in the Wagtail documentation, just pages on RichText internals about how to customise the editor in the admin.

Comment: Have you read the Draftail docs? https://www.draftail.org/docs/getting-started
You can use Draftail in isolation of Wagtail, it is built on Draft.js (which is a text editor library).

Comment: Yes, but does that mean I have to run two separate installs of Draftail?  I was hoping to use the one already installed on Wagtail.